# backgroundColor not background-color

Tags: javascript, css

Why using `background-color` doesn't work when changing the style by Javascript as I make it in `CSS` ?

This works :

```
document.getElementById("circ").style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
```

But this doesn't work :

```
document.getElementById("circ").style.background-color = getRandomColor();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`-` is [the **subtraction operator**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-subtraction-operator-minus). It can't appear in an identifier, which a dot notation property is.

You can use the `background-color` property name too, you just have to use a notation that allows `-` characters in it.

```js
document.body.style["background-color"] = "blue";
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript the `-` is a subtraction operator, so with that code what you're telling it to do is this:

> take a variable named "background" on an object called "style"
>
> subtract the value of a variable named "color" from it
>
> set that equal to the results of getRandomColor()

Which doesn't really make a lot of sense. Which is why css styles that have dashes in them are referenced in camelCase in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

**backgroundColor** is the property name. That's it.